# Updated: Does Props[MyActor] create a Props instance in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm learning Akka (in Scala), and constantly I come across Akka actors being created in this way:

```
val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "myactor2")
```

I don't understand it in that: I think `Props[MyActor]` is a class/type, but not a `Props` instance of type `Props[MyActor]`. (I'm not sure if my understanding is correct).

`ActorSystem.actorOf()` expects an instance of type `Props[T]` for some specific `T`. So my question is, why is it not `system.actorOf(Props[MyActor](), "myactor2")` (appending parentheses)?

**---- updated @19th, Sep ----**

I tried sth. like this in the Scala REPL:

```
object CX {
  def apply[T]() = new CX
}

class CX

object CX2 {
  def apply() = new CX2
}

class CX2
```

And find that `val x2 = CX2` is of type `CX2.type`, while `val x = CX[Int]` will actually create a `CX` instance.

```
scala> val x = CX[Int]
x: CX = CX@3b51cbf7

scala> val x2 = CX2
x2: CX2.type = CX2$@11314183
```

This is what really confuses me in the `Props[T]` creation.

Why does `CX` not create a `CX` instance, as `CX[Int]` does? Are there any docs or specs that elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Props` case class does not take a type parameter, as you already pointed out, but the `apply` method of `Props`'s companion object provides a [utility method](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Props$.html#apply[T%3C:akka.actor.Actor]()(implicitevidence$1:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):akka.actor.Props):

```
def apply[T <: Actor]()(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Props
```

This is the method that is being used in your example.

> why is it not `system.actorOf(Props[MyActor](), "myactor2")` (appending parentheses)?

You could do that too, sure. That is effectively what you do when you follow the [reccommended practice](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#recommended-practices) of creating a `props` factory method in your actor's companion object.

**-- Update 19th September --**

I think that you are mixing a couple of things here.

First, the construction of `Props[T]`. As previously mentioned, that uses an implicit `ClassTag[T]` to know what type to build. More information about `TypeTag` and `ClassTag` can be found [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html). So, the `CX` and `CX2` example you added is not really the same thing as the `Props[T]` scenario.

Second, and most important for your question, the `apply` on `CX2` object has parenthesis, but you are calling it without them. While that will compile (it will give you a warning though), it makes for the confusing scenario you highlighted. The hint here is that `val x2 = CX2` is of type `CX2.type` **-- which is the type of `CX2`'s object, not the class**. 
What is happening is that you have a `def apply()` with no parenthesis and no other distinguishing factor from the `CX2` object instance itself. So when you call it *without parenthesis* the compiler goes something like "The only way I can refer to the object is `CX2`, while the `apply` can be referred by both `CX2` and `CX2()`. I will then assume that `CX2` refers to the object and `CX2()` to the `apply`". To verify that is what is happening, you can try `val y = CX2()` and notice that it will have the type you expect.

Hope this clarifies a bit the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The companion object to Props has a [zero-argument apply method](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Props$.html#apply[T%3C:akka.actor.Actor]()(implicitevidence$1:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):akka.actor.Props), which takes a type argument and creates a default Props object for that type.  `Props[MyActor]` and `Props[MyActor]()` are the same thing in contexts where a value is expected (e.g. in calling `system.actorOf`).